# URL checking function returns false? PHP

Tags: php

First of all, I am not sure at all, but most of SQL injections, XSS attacks etc, occurs via the URL, using GET parameters.

So I wondered, what if I could clean them all and detect if there is an illegal word, if yes, exit to 404 page.

So this is my function:

```
    private static function cleanPath()
    {
        if (isset($_GET))
        {
            $count      = 0;
            $illegal    = array 
            (
                '<?', '<?php', '?>', '(', ')',
                '{', '}', 'SELECT', '*', 'FROM',
                'WHERE', 'select', 'from', 'where',
                'DELETE', 'delete', 'echo', 'print',
                'html', 'div', 'class', 'function',
                'prepare', 'query', 'execute', 'exec_',
                '_', '++', 'bindvalue', 'static',
                '$'
            );

            foreach ($illegal as $i)
            {
                foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
                {
                    $check = strpos($key, $i);
                    if (!$check)
                    {
                        $count++;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ((int)$count == count($illegal))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                echo $count . ' array count:' . count($illegal) . '<br />';
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

But it seems like the function doesn't work correctly.

And I enter this link: `?section=register&sec`

it will return false.

When I enter this link: `?section=register&section`

It will return true, and if I enter anything besides section, it will return false.
Why is it doing that?

as you see I already debugged that, and that's what it returns:

```
62 array count:31
```

So `$count = 62 and array count = 31`

Why does it go to 62? Looks like it is doubling the counter.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: You wont filter every bad word, any attempt to do so is futile, why not whitelist good words

Comment: This problem is already solved. It really is easier to just use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

Comment: You can do it your way or just use PHP/PDO and htmlspecialchars() to prevent XSS

Comment: I already use PDO for months now, this is just additional security.

Comment: You won't need additional security if you've coded it right

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 3):

Going by your logic, if everything is ok, the actual comparison to check that would be:

```
if ((int)$count == (count($_GET) * count($illegal)))
```

since the counter is being incremented for every GET parameter for every illegal term.

Having said that, the approach you use for this problem is almost impossible to be even extensive, let alone be complete.

It is better to sanitize the inputs and use programming constructs that prevent illegal values from being processed (as Anigel mentioned, whitelisting what you want), than to search for what are the wrongdoing constructs.